# Why does the Discord JavaScript library gives me this error?

Tags: discord.js

I'm getting an error like this.

```
Error [DISALLOWED_INTENTS]: Privileged intent provided is not enabled or whitelisted.
    at WebSocketManager.createShards (/home/runner/Discord-500-Commands-Bot-1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:245:15)
    at async Client.login (/home/runner/Discord-500-Commands-Bot-1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:254:7)
[15:16]
```

Windows 20

I tried to upgrade from version 9 to version 15 but it wouldn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error explains it all!

1. Head over to [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro) and select your application.
2. Click on **Bot** and scroll down to **Privileged Gateway Intents**
3. Enable the required ones and you're good to go!

Read more about these intents [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#privileged-intents)